# WPF binding to custom control (textbox) not working

Tags: wpf, binding, custom-controls

i wrote a simple custom control that inherits from textbox and uses a custom inputbox to enter text:

```
class TextTextbox : TextBox
{

    public string InputBoxTitle { get; set; }

    public string Input { get; set; }

    public TextTextbox()
    {
        PreviewMouseDown += MyTextbox_MouseDown;
    }

    private void MyTextbox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        var dialog = new BFH.InputBox.InputBox(InputBoxTitle, Input);
        dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (!dialog.Canceled)
            tb.Text = dialog.Input;
        else
            tb.Text = Input;
    }
}
```

i use it in the view like this:

```
<CustomControls:TextTextbox Text="{Binding Test}" InputBoxTitle="Titel" Input="Input"/>
```

in the vm for tests:

```
private string _test;
public string Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set
        {
            if (_test == value)
                return;
            _test = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Test");
        }
    }
```

but the binding to `Test` is not working. in the view, i see that the text of the textbox does change, but i seems not to be linked to the property of the VM. i added a button with `MessageBox.Show(Test)`, but it is always empty. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure there is some `DataContext` for the control? it will be used as an implicit `Source` for the `Binding`.

Comment: @user3815356 Test using `Text="{Binding}"`, that will print the `DataContext`

Comment: Just a note: in a derived TextBox class it is not necessary to attach an event handler to the class' own `PreviewMouseDown` event. You may instead just override the protected `OnPreviewMouseDown` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the binding's `UpdateSourceTrigger` property to `PropertyChanged`. Otherwise the source property `Test` will not be updated before the TextBox loses focus.

```
<CustomControls:TextTextbox
    Text="{Binding Test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ... />
```

---

From the *Examples* section on the [`Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) page on MSDN:

> The TextBox.Text property has a default UpdateSourceTrigger value of
>   LostFocus. This means if an application has a TextBox with a
>   data-bound TextBox.Text property, the text you type into the TextBox
>   does not update the source until the TextBox loses focus (for
>   instance, when you click away from the TextBox).