# Binding a TextBox to a property of a class

Tags: wpf

Maybe this is awfully wrong. I have a text box and want the value in that text box to be synchronized with a member of a class. I thought I use binding but I cannot get a handle on it. What I tried is below and does not work. Where am I thinking wrong?

Here is my XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="tt_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tt_WPF"
    Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBox x:Name="tb" Width="200" Text="{Binding local:abc.Name}"></TextBox>
       <Button Click="Button_Click">Ok</Button>
    </StackPanel> </Window>
```

And here the code behind:

```
public class ABC
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ABC abc = new ABC();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use a MVVM toolset, consider how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291518/inotifypropertychanged-vs-dependencyproperty-in-viewmodel    And without tabbing out, the bound property might not update without addressing http://stackoverflow.com/a/25864134/3225  And, it's also quite typical to set the DataContext of the View/Window with the intance of the object you're binding to

Comment: Start reading the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and raise the property changed event on ABC.Name.

You'll want to set the ABC object in your MainWindow.cs as the data context and bind Name to `TextBox.Text`. In the code-behind:

```
public ABC MyABC { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   MyABC = new ABC();
   DataContext = MyABC;
}
```

And bind in XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb" Width="200" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"/>
```

Comment: changing DataContext = this; to DataContext = MyABC; worked for me